# Preventing certain words from appearing on a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, regex

Let's say that I have a big Google spreadsheet that multiple users have access to, and I'm not able to control which users have access to it. I have a concern for trolls.

How would I prevent people from entering certain words, specifically slurs and curse words, something fancy with regex in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use regexmatch with the "custom formula" option on the data validation menu item.

Create a list of all the words you want to reject and join them with the `|` as your delimiter, which represents "or" in regex.

I recommend leaving them lower case and then within the formula we will also lowercase the text to make sure we catch both cases/scenarios, but for example I did the validation on all of column H:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(H:H),"then|text"),False,True)
```

The words I chose to reject were `then` and `text` - if you choose not to reject the input but just flag it it will look like the image below, alternatively you can choose "reject input" and that will literally reject any cell they try to enter that contains your offensive strings.

[image]

PS if you choose reject, it wont ever even get entered in like it does in the image - i just wasnt able to capture an event NOT occurring in a photograph lol

Answer (score 1):

The following code is active throughout the spreadsheet and it's called an *onEdit* trigger.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  return e.value ? (listBadWords(e.value) !== -1 ? e.range.clearContent() : null) : null;  
}

function listBadWords(word) {
  // source: https://github.com/LDNOOBW/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/blob/master/en
  var listEN = [
    '2g1c','2 girls 1 cup','acrotomophilia','alabama hot pocket','alaskan pipeline','anal','anilingus','anus','apeshit','arsehole','ass','asshole','assmunch','auto erotic','autoerotic','babeland',
    'baby batter','baby juice','ball gag','ball gravy','ball kicking','ball licking','ball sack','ball sucking','bangbros','bareback','barely legal','barenaked','bastard','bastardo','bastinado','bbw',
    'bdsm','beaner','beaners','beaver cleaver','beaver lips','bestiality','big black','big breasts','big knockers','big tits','bimbos','birdlock','bitch','bitches','black cock','blonde action','blonde on blonde action',
    'blowjob','blow job','blow your load','blue waffle','blumpkin','bollocks','bondage','boner','boob','boobs','booty call','brown showers','brunette action','bukkake','bulldyke','bullet vibe','bullshit','bung hole',
    'bunghole','busty','butt','buttcheeks','butthole','camel toe','camgirl','camslut','camwhore','carpet muncher','carpetmuncher','chocolate rosebuds','circlejerk','cleveland steamer','clit','clitoris','clover clamps',
    'clusterfuck','cock','cocks','coprolagnia','coprophilia','cornhole','coon','coons','creampie','cum','cumming','cunnilingus','cunt','darkie','date rape','daterape','deep throat','deepthroat','dendrophilia','dick','dildo',
    'dingleberry','dingleberries','dirty pillows','dirty sanchez','doggie style','doggiestyle','doggy style','doggystyle','dog style','dolcett','domination','dominatrix','dommes','donkey punch','double dong','double penetration',
    'dp action','dry hump','dvda','eat my ass','ecchi','ejaculation','erotic','erotism','escort','eunuch','faggot','fecal','felch','fellatio','feltch','female squirting','femdom','figging','fingerbang','fingering','fisting',
    'foot fetish','footjob','frotting','fuck','fuck buttons','fuckin','fucking','fucktards','fudge packer','fudgepacker','futanari','gang bang','gay sex','genitals','giant cock','girl on','girl on top','girls gone wild',
    'goatcx','goatse','god damn','gokkun','golden shower','goodpoop','goo girl','goregasm','grope','group sex','g-spot','guro','hand job','handjob','hard core','hardcore','hentai','homoerotic','honkey','hooker','hot carl',
    'hot chick','how to kill','how to murder','huge fat','humping','incest','intercourse','jack off','jail bait','jailbait','jelly donut','jerk off','jigaboo','jiggaboo','jiggerboo','jizz','juggs','kike','kinbaku','kinkster',
    'kinky','knobbing','leather restraint','leather straight jacket','lemon party','lolita','lovemaking','make me come','male squirting','masturbate','menage a trois','milf','missionary position','motherfucker','mound of venus',
    'mr hands','muff diver','muffdiving','nambla','nawashi','negro','neonazi','nigga','nigger','nig nog','nimphomania','nipple','nipples','nsfw images','nude','nudity','nympho','nymphomania','octopussy','omorashi',
    'one cup two girls','one guy one jar','orgasm','orgy','paedophile','paki','panties','panty','pedobear','pedophile','pegging','penis','phone sex','piece of shit','pissing','piss pig','pisspig','playboy','pleasure chest',
    'pole smoker','ponyplay','poof','poon','poontang','punany','poop chute','poopchute','porn','porno','pornography','prince albert piercing','pthc','pubes','pussy','queaf','queef','quim','raghead','raging boner','rape',
    'raping','rapist','rectum','reverse cowgirl','rimjob','rimming','rosy palm','rosy palm and her 5 sisters','rusty trombone','sadism','santorum','scat','schlong','scissoring','semen','sex','sexo','sexy','shaved beaver',
    'shaved pussy','shemale','shibari','shit','shitblimp','shitty','shota','shrimping','skeet','slanteye','slut','s&m','smut','snatch','snowballing','sodomize','sodomy','spic','splooge','splooge moose','spooge','spread legs',
    'spunk','strap on','strapon','strappado','strip club','style doggy','suck','sucks','suicide girls','sultry women','swastika','swinger','tainted love','taste my','tea bagging','threesome','throating','tied up','tight white',
    'tit','tits','titties','titty','tongue in a','topless','tosser','towelhead','tranny','tribadism','tub girl','tubgirl','tushy','twat','twink','twinkie','two girls one cup','undressing','upskirt','urethra play','urophilia',
    'vagina','venus mound','vibrator','violet wand','vorarephilia','voyeur','vulva','wank','wetback','wet dream','white power','wrapping men','wrinkled starfish','xx','xxx','yaoi','yellow showers','yiffy','zoophilia'
  ];
  return listEN.indexOf(word);
}
```

### Explained

When the trigger is fired, it will check if there's something to check for. If yes, it will pass the word (`e.value`) on to the *listBadWords* function. If it found a corresponding word (meaning not -1), it will clear the content of the cell, else it will do nothing.

Past this code into the script editor of your spreadsheet (*Tools > SCript editor...*) and press the save button. Now the *onEdit* trigger is functional.

Comment: This works well. But can this be applied to the entire sheet with existing data? Currently, onedit works only when you add or edit something. If something was already added, or if you copy and paste a profanity word in the spreadsheet, the script won't clear it.

Comment: And it seems like this only works if the exact word is found. If the word is a substring or used in a sentence, it isn't blocked. How can the script be modified to treat each word as a substring?